# Parallel recursive function in Python

Tags: python, concurrency, recursion, multiprocessing

How do I parallelize a recursive function in Python?

My function looks like this:

```
def f(x, depth):
    if x==0:
        return ...
    else :
        return [x] + map(lambda x:f(x, depth-1), list_of_values(x))

def list_of_values(x):
    # Heavy compute, pure function
```

When trying to parallelize it with `multiprocessing.Pool.map`, Windows opens an infinite number of processes and hangs.

What's a good (preferably simple) way to parallelize it (for a single multicore machine)?

Here is the code that hangs:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
pool = pool(processes=4)
def f(x, depth):
    if x==0:
        return ...
    else :
        return [x] + pool.map(lambda x:f(x, depth-1), list_of_values(x))

def list_of_values(x):
    # Heavy compute, pure function
```

Comment: what is the return type of `f`?  it seems like it returns a list.  but what is the type of a list element?  this is what i am stuck on (code similar to answer below).  it seems like it may be a list of lists?  and each of those may be a list?  or is something wrong above?

Comment: X is a tree leaf. return type is a tree , in lisp notation [head , subtrees] )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, sorry for the problems with this.

I'm going to answer a slightly different question where `f()` returns the sum of the values in the list.  That is because it's not clear to me from your example what the return type of `f()` would be, and using an integer makes the code simple to understand.

This is complex because there are two different things happening in parallel:

1. the calculation of the expensive function in the pool
2. the recursive expansion of `f()`

I am very careful to only use the pool to calculate the expensive function.  In that way we don't get an "explosion" of processes, but because this is asynchronous we need to postpone a *lot* of work for the callback that the worker calls once the expensive function is done.

More than that, we need to use a countdown latch so that we know when all the separate sub-calls to `f()` are complete.

There may be a simpler way (I am pretty sure there is, but I need to do other things), but perhaps this gives you an idea of what is possible:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, Value, RawArray, RLock
from time import sleep

class Latch:

    '''A countdown latch that lets us wait for a job of "n" parts'''

    def __init__(self, n):
        self.__counter = Value('i', n)
        self.__lock = RLock()

    def decrement(self):
        with self.__lock:
            self.__counter.value -= 1
            print('dec', self.read())
        return self.read() == 0

    def read(self):
        with self.__lock:
            return self.__counter.value

    def join(self):
        while self.read():
            sleep(1)


def list_of_values(x):
    '''An expensive function'''
    print(x, ': thinking...')
    sleep(1)
    print(x, ': thought')
    return list(range(x))


pool = Pool()


def async_f(x, on_complete=None):
    '''Return the sum of the values in the expensive list'''
    if x == 0:
        on_complete(0) # no list, return 0
    else:
        n = x # need to know size of result beforehand
        latch = Latch(n) # wait for n entires to be calculated
        result = RawArray('i', n+1) # where we will assemble the map
        def delayed_map(values):
            '''This is the callback for the pool async process - it runs
               in a separate thread within this process once the
               expensive list has been calculated and orchestrates the
               mapping of f over the result.'''
            result[0] = x # first value in list is x
            for (v, i) in enumerate(values):
                def callback(fx, i=i):
                    '''This is the callback passed to f() and is called when
                       the function completes.  If it is the last of all the
                       calls in the map then it calls on_complete() (ie another
                       instance of this function) for the calling f().'''
                    result[i+1] = fx
                    if latch.decrement(): # have completed list
                        # at this point result contains [x]+map(f, ...)
                        on_complete(sum(result)) # so return sum
                async_f(v, callback)
        # Ask worker to generate list then call delayed_map
        pool.apply_async(list_of_values, [x], callback=delayed_map)


def run():
    '''Tie into the same mechanism as above, for the final value.'''
    result = Value('i')
    latch = Latch(1)
    def final_callback(value):
        result.value = value
        latch.decrement()
    async_f(6, final_callback)
    latch.join() # wait for everything to complete
    return result.value


print(run())
```

PS: I am using Python 3.2 and the ugliness above is because we are delaying computation of the final results (going back up the tree) until later.  It's possible something like generators or futures could simplify things.

Also, I suspect you need a cache to avoid needlessly recalculating the expensive function when called with the same argument as earlier.

See also [yaniv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222570/parallell-recursive-function-in-python/7228414#7228414) - which seems to be an alternative way to reverse the order of the evaluation by being explicit about depth.

Comment: 1. define the pool inside the function. 2. before the line mentioned, compute the list_of_values using apply. 3. close the pool.

Comment: interesting.  thanks for the info.  going to play with this myself now... :o)

Comment: Andrew could you please explain how pool.apply works ? because this doesn't seem something you can paralellize: applying a function to a single argument. But when i try it(even with Pool(processes=1)) , i get great results.

Comment: i am unsure myself, now.  i can explain what pool.appy does - it just runs the function elsewhere - but i cannot explain why it helps here (and i think my answer is wrong).  i am battling with some work of my own, but i will come back to this and update my answer when i understand more (probably within the next 12 hours).

Comment: Thanks!!. i'll also research this.

Comment: After digging a bit more into it:because i did all my tests in the ide's debugger, and the pool.apply works outside of the debugger, it was faster. but in real life comparison , they give similar time.

Comment: ok, i've updated the answer and am calling this a day...  hope it helps.  i suspect there is a much more elegant solution, but that's all i could find quickly.

Comment: Andrew, since your solution is a complete one , it should be the definitive answer. but please link to my partial but simpler solution below.

Comment: could you explain why you need async function ?

Answer (score 3):

After thinking about this, I found a simple, not complete, but good enough answer:

```
# A partially parallel solution. Just do the first level of recursion in parallel. It might be enough work to fill all cores.
import multiprocessing

def f_helper(data):
     return f(x=data['x'],depth=data['depth'], recursion_depth=data['recursion_depth'])

def f(x, depth, recursion_depth):
    if depth==0:
        return ...
    else :
        if recursion_depth == 0:
            pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
            result = [x] + pool.map(f_helper, [{'x':_x, 'depth':depth-1,  'recursion_depth':recursion_depth+1 } _x in list_of_values(x)])
            pool.close()
        else:
            result = [x] + map(f_helper, [{'x':_x, 'depth':depth-1, 'recursion_depth':recursion_depth+1 } _x in list_of_values(x)])


        return result

def list_of_values(x):
    # Heavy compute, pure function
```

Answer (score 1):

I store the main process id initially and transfer it to sub programs.

When I need to start a multiprocessing job, I check the number of children of the main process. If it is less than or equal to the half of my CPU count, then I run it as parallel. If it greater than the half of my CPU count, then I run it serial. In this way, it avoids bottlenecks and uses CPU cores effectively. You can tune the number of cores for your case. For example, you can set it to the exact number of CPU cores, but you should not exceed it.

```
def subProgramhWrapper(func, args):
    func(*args)

parent = psutil.Process(main_process_id)
children = parent.children(recursive=True)
num_cores = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count()/2)

if num_cores >= len(children):
    #parallel run
    pool = MyPool(num_cores)
    results = pool.starmap(subProgram, input_params)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
else:
    #serial run
    for input_param in input_params:
        subProgramhWrapper(subProgram, input_param)
```